# Is a simple linear regression appropriate for an originally ordinal outcome variable?

Tags: regression, linear-regression, logistic-regression

**Context:** To form an index, I summed (and weighted) 2 variables containing ratings (1-9).

**Potentially problem:** Wondering if it is appropriate to conduct a linear regression, all other assumptions being met, even though the individual component ratings of this outcome variable are technically ordinal? I think the alternative is an ordinal logistic regression.

Comment: I think there's nothing wrong with this, but a lot depends on the data and the goal of course.

Comment: Thanks. What if the ratings made on a 9-point likert scale were first averaged, then summed, and then 2 variables were summed together to create the final index? The subsequent analysis is to see whether there is a trend over time (hence linear regression).

Comment: I don't follow the calculation: normally there's only one value as a result from an average, so I'm not sure what is summed at the end! But otherwise I don't see any problem with applying linear reg on the result, the fact that the original values are ordinal doesn't matter imho.